# launch sudo from shell with php

Tags: php, linux

How can I run this from PHP?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a good idea.

Also, have a look to the following discussions:

[Can PHP restart Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425717/can-php-restart-apache)

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-security/3068-using-php-restart-apache.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exec command. http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

If you want to use sudo, just add the user Apache is running under (usually www) in the /etc/sudoers file.