# restart/reload apache services via php

Tags: php, linux, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP restart Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425717/can-php-restart-apache)

Hello,

I want to restart/reload httpd services via the web browser, is it possible if so how.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425717/can-php-restart-apache ?

Comment: I would think you can with a shell script call, but I think the biggest issue is going to be permissions. If your user running apache can run admin level commands... yikes.

Comment: @spyrosP that was quick, in the hurry you forgot to check if an answer was accepted

Comment: @Jean, just because somebody did not accept an answer, it doesn't mean it's not there. I'm pretty sure you haven't read that after i posted the duplicate. That is why you replied in 3 minutes. Now take the time to check the duplicate, because the answer is there.

Comment: @spyrosp i did check, else how would i know if an answer was not accepted, also if there is accepted answer then that is  solution, so if you have a solution, then post it

Comment: @Jean, every single answer in that question is correct in it's own way.  This is not something you should be doing with PHP (*because it requires root access*), but there are lots of ways to get it done in both PHP and using other, more appropriate methods.

Comment: @Jean : I have a solution, it lies here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425717/can-php-restart-apache . I paste the link again, because once again, you did not read anything, you just checked to see if marked to provide a childish argument about it. Cause if you had, you would have already seen the solution. Suit yourself.

Comment: @spyrosp could copy/paste the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming linux or something *nixish)
Create a shell script which restarts the server

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Make it executeable and set the SUID bit

```
chmod +xs /path/to/script.sh
```

And from PHP simply

```
exec("/path/to/script.sh")
```

Problem solved.

Edit: Actually this wont work, because the suid shell script wont start the other shell script with suid.

You could add a line to your /etc/sudoers files which allows the script to be executed without password and then

```
sudo /path/to/script.sh
```

That should work.